# Why is this thrown exception duplicated?

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, zend-controller-plugin

This is a follow up question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365770/hooking-into-the-error-processing-cycle), which is not really important.

I have written the following front controller plugin:

```
public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $monitor = Zend_Registry::get('monitor');
    
    if ($response->isException())
    {
        $monitor->log($response);
    }
}
```

Where $monitor is an instance of a custom DB logging class (extending Zend_Log).

In the log method of the Monitor I loop over the Array of Zend_Exceptions returned by $response->getException().

For testing purposes I through an exception in an action:

```
throw new Zend_Exception('the big test', 555);
```

Most things work as expected, the Exception is written to the database.

#### Question

But, it's written twice. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the dispatch loop is called twice. First for the current action and then for default:error:error :) Place the log into `dispatchLoopShutdown()` method